# Change rendering order of controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I found this article on how to manipulate the rendering sequence of asp.net controls.: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2007/09/07/rendering-asp-net-controls-out-of-order.aspx
I placed some placeholders on the page to encapsulate the controls i want to move around. The problem is, that RenderChildren does render the controls without the html i placed into the placeholder like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="phOneToMove" Runat="server" Visible="true">
<tr>
<td><asp:Literal id="label1" Runat="server">Caption</asp:Literal></td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validator1" Enabled="true" ControlToValidate="textbox1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
</tr>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

The controls are rendered without the `tr` and `td` around.
How can I handle this? All I want is to change the order of the placeholders like in this example `phOneToMove`.

Note: I am running on asp.net 2.0.

Comment: Show the Render method.
The <tr><td> etc. are transformed as Label controls by ASP.NET. If you only render the controls you explicitly know, you will miss these tr/td.

Comment: No it's even not working if I use the example from the blogpost:

    private void RenderReverse(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
    for (int i = Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Controls[i].RenderControl(writer);
    }
    }

Comment: And what is the non-working result ?

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. The HTML-Tags outside of all direct subcontrols of my control are not rendered. As soon as i place them into a placeholder as well it works. Doesn't html-code show up as childcontrols as  well?. I have no code to skip any controls out of the process of rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My problem was, that the literal html elements (not LiteralControls) were not in the Controls property of my usercontrol. I did not know why. So I started to debug the .net Framework code itself ans setup a project with no overhead.

Short: I had code in the ascx file itself like `<b><%= myOutputVariable %></b>`. This causes asp to not put the literal content of a file into the controls collection. After I removed this code it worked like expected.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags are stored as controls of tyep Literal or LiteralControl, so however th elogic works has to check for controls of that type to ensure they get to their destination too.